# dividir un elemento de una lista separado por un signo y crear dos lista con cada parte de la lista en python

Tags: python, lista

necesito crear dos listas, date y price. Esto es lo que tengo hasta ahora.

```
mylist = list(input().split(" ")) # para insertar los valores dados
data = []
price = [] 

for i in mylist: 
  data.append(i).split("|", 1)
  price.append(i).split("|", -1)
```

Pero tengo este error: `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'split'`

Me podrian ayudar? Muchas gracias

Estos son los valores con los que estoy trabajando:

2016-01-01|22.05
2016-01-02|22.45
2016-01-03|23.57

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Al leer con input obtienes una cadena que puedes convertir en lista aplicando `split`. Si no indicas cómo dividir la cadena, está se divide por los *white-spaces*, tantos como haya, lo que es más general que `split(" ")`.

```
mylist = input().split()
data = []
price = []
```

Ahora que mylist es una cadena así:

```
['2016-01-01|22.05', '2016-01-02|22.45', '2016-01-03|23.57']
```

sólo queda recorrer la lista y separar cada elemento por "|"

```
for par in mylist:
    fecha, precio = par.split("|")
    data.append(fecha)
    price.append(precio)

print(data)
print(price)
```

Lo que genera:

```
['2016-01-01', '2016-01-02', '2016-01-03']
['22.05', '22.45', '23.57']
```

Comment: Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 0):

En tu código:

```
for i in mylist: 
  data.append(i).split("|", 1)
  price.append(i).split("|", -1)
```

Estás aplicando `split()` al resultado devuelto por `append(i)`. Este método retorna `None` y de ahí el error. Por otro lado no es eso lo que querías hacer, pues estás añadiendo el valor completo de `i` a tu lista. Lo que quieres hacer es **antes** dividir `i` en trozos y después añadir cada trozo a una lista diferente.

Esto sería por tanto así:

```
for i in mylist: 
  trozos = i.split("|")
  data.append(trozos[0])
  price.append(trozos[-1])
```

Comment: Tienes toda la razón. Me lo imaginaba pero no estaba segura. Muchas gracias.